# Why am i getting undefined for this variable?

Tags: javascript

I have this variable `test1 = []`, I push some `res.json` to it.
I expect it to be something like this `[[{json,json}]]`, but turns out it gives me undefined when I try to iterate it like this `test1[0]`.
Can someone explain to me how is `test1[0]` undefined? And how can I get values from it?

Below is the chrome console output for this variable.
[image]

snippet:
test1 = data_array

```
var data_array = []
const BookingHistory = getBookings(userDbID).then((json) => {data_array.push(json)})

console.log("test1", data_array[0]) //undefined
```

getBookings:

```
export const getBookings = (userDbId) => {
    const id = userDbId; //one of the global state that is sent to Date from App
  
    // Create our request constructor with all the parameters we need
    const request = new Request(`/users/${id}/bookings`)

    return fetch(request)
        .then((res) => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          return res.json();
        }
        })
        .then((json) => {return json})
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
}
```

Comment: See [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays) (the array is empty when you try to access it in code.)

Comment: Add a snippet rather than a photo

Comment: A snippet is the minimum code needed to reproduce. Create a simple array, console.log his first values (as you're doing), and show the exact problem. Learning how to create snippet will really help you onwards. You can create a snippet by clicking on edit, and then the `<>` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fetch()` function is asynchronous. It returns a `Promise`, meaning that its return value is not evaluated immediately. If you want to use its return value, you must do it in the handler function (or you use `async/await` syntax). You could modify your code like so:

```js
let data_array = []
const BookingHistory = getBookings(userDbID).then((json) => {
  // This only runs after response from fetch request arrives. Not immediately
  data_array.push(json);
  console.log(data_array[0]);  // Correct value this time, data_array is no longer an empty array
  ... // The rest of the code that makes use of the updated value of data_array variable
})

console.log("test1", data_array) // This evaluates data_array immediately so, at this point, data_array is still an empty array
```

Comment: That's the real problem here, the chrome console is kinda misleading me! Thank you for your patience kind sir :)